# Error when trying to use write.xlsx after uploading the package

Tags: r

Here goes the errors when I am trying to use `write.xlsx` after uploading the package.

```
library("xlsx", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
Loading required package: rJava
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
cannot open file 'C:/Users/nm/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rJava/R/rJava.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
library("rJava", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
cannot open file 'C:/Users/nm/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rJava/R/rJava.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Comment: Similar questions with `rJava` problems http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+rJava or try another package like `openxlsx`

Comment: Did you load the 'rJava' library? `libray('rJava)`, maybe you need to install it first

Comment: Hi I did install rJava, had a problem uploading, it gave to following error: > library("rJava", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
>

Comment: Thank you Pierre, I'll check it out